# Как передать переменную в function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

Мне нужно передать id видео ютуб ролика в плеер ютуба. Не пойму как это сделать.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'app/php/ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'view_archive_post',
            user_id: user_id,
            post_id: $(this).closest('.col-md').data('post')
        },
        success(data) {
            
            data.forEach(postdata => { 

                $(".post-id").text(postdata.post_id)
                $(".title-post-archive").text(postdata.post_title)
                $('.date-post-archive').text(postdata.post_publish)

                var idvideo = postdata.post_content.split('=')[1]

               //console.log(idvideo)
               return idvideo
         })
     }
})


var tag = document.createElement('script')
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api"
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag)

var ytplayer
var idvideo = 'vlDzYIIOYmM' <-- сюда мне нужно передать id

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    ytplayer = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        height: '360',
        width: '640',
        videoId: idvideo
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var idvideo;

function setIdVideo(id){
    idvideo = id;
}    

$.ajax({
        url: 'app/php/ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'view_archive_post',
            user_id: user_id,
            post_id: $(this).closest('.col-md').data('post')
        },
        success(data) {
            
            data.forEach(postdata => { 

                $(".post-id").text(postdata.post_id);
                $(".title-post-archive").text(postdata.post_title);
                $('.date-post-archive').text(postdata.post_publish);

                var idvideo = postdata.post_content.split('=')[1];

               //console.log(idvideo)
               setIdVideo(idvideo);
         })
     }
});


var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var ytplayer;


function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    ytplayer = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        height: '360',
        width: '640',
        videoId: idvideo
    });
}
```